# $2^n + 3$ and $2^{n+1} + 3$ both prime?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, exponential-function, mersenne-numbers

It seems there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^n + 3$.

It seems that the density is about the same density as primes below $n$ at least for small $n$.

What surprised me is I found solutions to $2^n + 3$ and $2^{n+1} + 3$ both prime.

Is the density of that about the same density as prime twins below $n$ ?

I will add some data later.

Any references to these ?

$f(n) = 2^n + 3$ is prime for

$n =$

$1,
2,
3,
4,
6,
7,
12,
15,
16,
18,
28,
30,
55,
67$

added :

Conjecture :

If $f(k)$ and $f(k+1)$ are prime then

$$\frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} < e$$

I could split up the question if that conjecture gets answered, well actually It might not be provable since the list is not proven infinite but a counterexample or strong argument maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure about your conjecture that the density is about the same as primes below $n$. OEIS has the sequence of $n$ such that $2^n+3$ is prime, and they get pretty spread out: https://oeis.org/A057732

Comment: The exponents giving a prime upto $10^4$ are : $$[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 12, 15, 16, 18, 28, 30, 55, 67, 84, 228, 390, 784, 1110, 1704, 2008, 2139, 2191, 2367, 2370, 4002, 4060, 4062, 4552, 5547, 8739]$$ , $1/2,2/3,3/4,6/7,15/16$ are the consecutive cases upto this limit.

Comment: Generalize to y and (y-3)*2+3 prime?

Comment: For large $n$, $(2^{n+1}+3)/(2^n+3)$ is very close to two (so, way less than $e$), whether either they are prime or not.

Comment: Standard heuristics would suggest (but not prove!) there are only finitely many $n$ such that $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ are both prime. Maybe $n=15$ is the last example....

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A057732